# How to delete a string based on spaces

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a std::string 
I want to keep the string after two spaces like in Newa and Newb

```cpp
std::string a = "Command send SET Command comes here";
std::string b = "Command GET Command comes here"; 

std::string Newa = "SET Command comes here";
std::string Newb = "Command comes here";
```

what comes to my mind is that i can do `std::string::find(' ')` two times and use `std::string::substr` to get the desired result.

Can we do it in more refined manner.

Comment: Why not `std::string::find("  ")` (with two spaces in double quotes)? There are multiple flavors of [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), including one which accepts `const char*` (for a C string) as pattern.

Comment: @Scheff i tried using two spaces in the quotes but i get result as -1    int test = stdtsrCommand.find("  ");

Comment: Two times `find` and one substr is probably the best you have. You can also write this as a oneliner if you wish. As a note: searching for two spaces, will do exactly that, search a space followed by a space, no magic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Scheff it is just typo to signify that it is std::string

Comment: @Scheff I think OP wants to cut the string after the _second_ space, not after a double space. At least his example looks like it. But I'm also a bit confused by it.

Comment: @churill Oops. You are right.

Comment: Fixed [Sample on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc075236342b115f) (after beeing enlighted by @churill). ;-)

Comment: What about using `std::copy_if` with a stateful lambda that remembers how many spaces it have ecnountered?

Comment: @churill, you may be right, but then `Newb` does not contain the right string? I would expect it to start with a leading space given the current description...

Comment: @Ton van den Heuval i have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a more generalized approach. `find_n` returns an iterator past the element that matches the `n`-th element that needs to be searched for. It can be used to split after two spaces, three spaces, etc. You can in fact use it as a building block for other algorithms. The split function will return the input string in case the string contains less than two spaces.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class InputIt, class T>
InputIt find_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value, size_t n)
{
  size_t count{0};
  while (first != last && count < n) {
    if (*first++ == value) ++count;
  }
  return first;
}

std::string split_after_two_spaces(const std::string& s)
{
  const auto it{find_n(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', 2)};
  if (it != s.end()) {
    return std::string(it, s.end());
  }

  return s;
}

int main()
{
  const std::string a = "Command send SET Command comes here";
  const std::string b = "Command GET Command comes here";
  const std::string c = "Command GET";

  std::cout << split_after_two_spaces(a) << '\n';
  std::cout << split_after_two_spaces(b) << '\n';
  std::cout << split_after_two_spaces(c) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

I wanted to verify how much worse this approach would be in terms of performance compared to the straightforward double `find()` and `substr()` approach, and it turns out to be a bit faster for small strings, and it is slower for longer input strings. `std::string::find()` is going to be faster than `std::find` since it is likely to be optimized to deal with strings specifically.

- Short string benchmark: http://quick-bench.com/sgKeT333zoXYBQS_1EXFzprCNrY
- Longer string benchmark: http://quick-bench.com/FEhPTU4YfDPvemWMqgg4oTHZlLU

*Update:* The following implementation of `find_n` is more efficient, but also a bit more complex unfortunately. It has nicer semantics in the sense that it returns an iterator to the `n`-th matching element, instead of an iterator one past the `n`-th matching element.

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
InputIt find_n(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value, size_t n)
{
  if (first != last && n > 0)
  {
    size_t count{0};
    do
    {
      first = std::find(first, last, value);
    }
    while (first != last && ++count < n);
  }

  return first;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, with the help of `sstream` and `getline`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a = "Command send SET Command comes here";
    stringstream ss(a);
    string w1, w2, w3, Newa;
    ss >> w1 >> w2 >> w3;
    getline(ss, Newa); //get rest of the string!
    cout << w3 + Newa << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
"SET Command comes here"
```

Comment: It would be more readable and efficient to use [`std::stringstream::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) if the first bits are actually ignored.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to construct `sstream`, you can just use `find()` function twice.

The function below can remove `n` first words from your string (based on spaces, but it can also be parametrized). All you need is to find the first space occurence using `find`, replace input string with a substring (starting from a next character after that space) and repeat the procedure depending on number of words you want to remove.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string removeWords(std::string s, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        const auto spaceIdx = s.find(' ');
        s = s.substr(spaceIdx+1, s.length());
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << removeWords("Command send SET Command comes here", 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << removeWords("Command GET Command comes here", 2) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, maybe I have a gross misunderstanding. I see many lines of descriptions, many lines of code, votings and an accepted answer.

But normally such text replacements can always be done with a one-liner. There is a dedicated function available for such tasks: `std::regex_replace`.

There are no requirements regarding performance, so I would recommend to use the dedicated function. Please see the following one-liner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string a{"Command send SET Command comes here"};

    std::regex_replace(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout), a.begin(), a.end(), std::regex(R"(.*? .*? (.*$))"), "$1");

    return 0;
}
```

I guess that because if its simplicity, further explanaions are not needed.